# Return Air Vent

Tags: walls, vent

I am in the middle of planning a kitchen remodel. We are removing a non load bearing wall to open up the space. The wall has a big return air vent (using the studs of the wall). My initial thought is to simply have a floor vent in its place once the wall is removed. Anybody have any advice/opinion?

Comment: Does the vent go up to an additional floor or is it only for that kitchen?

Comment: Nope! Thankfully the vent is only for what is now the "formal dining room". Great question, sorry I should have clarified from the beginning

Comment: Putting the return vent on the floor you will want to put a filter in because it will suck all the dust and dirt on the floor into your system.